# Restart wireless connections with command?

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, bluetooth

I have troubles with Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop dell precision 5530. My wireless connections are sometimes interrupted. When I open settings I see on wifi and bluetooth tab message **Wifi / BT adapter not found**.

I also tried restart network manager with command `sudo service network-manager restart` but doesn't work.

I find out temporary solution turn off laptop and start it again (I really mean turn off because restart doesn't solve it).

Can you tell me how can I fix wifi network when interrupted without turning my laptop off or how to fix it forever? Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly restarting the network service , try

```
    sudo service network-manager stop
    sudo service network-manager start
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a power management issue, open terminal and do

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
systemctl restart network-manager.service
```